# Why Tiskabel after Hallel on Rosh Hodesh and not other weekdays of Hanukka?

Tags: chanuka, shacharis-morning-prayer, kaddish, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chol-weekday

Why do we say a Tiskabel kaddish after Hallel on Rosh Hodesh and only a half-kaddish after Hallel on the other weekdays of Hanukka?  What is the general principle and rationale?

Comment: Why not also ask about the Kaddish after UVa LeTzion? On weekday-Chanukkah it's Kaddish-Tiskabel, but on RoshChodesh-Chanukkah it's half-Kaddish. The exact opposite phenomenon.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Perhaps this swap is part of the answer, but I do not see exactly how.

Comment: @YehudaW It's actually obviously part of the question. But notice how you always get one Tiskabbel on any day.

Comment: @DoubleAA. If the tiskabel kaddish comes at the end of a service (see #11 of http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/The_Fourteen_Principles_Of_Jewish_Prayer.pdf), where is te end of the service on these different days?

Comment: If that's your question, consider asking it.

Comment: @DoubleAA. It might be an obvious part of a question that you would ask, but it is not part of the question that I asked.

Comment: @YehudaW It's part of the question you are asking, whether you realized it at first or not. This is becoming a stupid argument. Just accept the relevant data and improve your question. You don't need to be stuck with what you started with. That's why we allow comments and editing. Please [edit] to improve your question, or [someone might do it for you](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=17

Answer (score 1):

See [Ba'er Hetev (par. 1) on O.C. 423:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=180)

The general rule is that any time Musaf is said that day, Kaddish Titkabel is said after Hallel, because this marks the end of Shacharit.

We deduce from this, that as there is no Musaph said on Chanukah, we say only half Kaddish.

Comment: I would need to research further as to what the presence of Musaph does, specifically, that he states that "this is where he ends Shacharit". He seems to state that Torah reading is a separate item, yet we do have Torah reading on Chanukah, as well.

Comment: Why does shacharit end before the torah reading on rosh hodesh but after the torah reading on the weekdays of hanukka?

Comment: @yehuda new questions should be asked separately. Too bad you mishandled this one...

Comment: @DoubleAA  I do not understand. My comment to this answer is a restatement of my question, as I see it.  What am I missing?

Comment: @YehudaW It seems that you asked both why it's done - meaning you want to know WHAT the rule is. That's what I answered. There's a separate question embedded asking what is the reasoning behind that rule. Perhaps, that should be a separate question.

Comment: I did ask "What is the general principle and rationale?" I thought that was reasonably part of the same question.

Comment: @YehudaW You explicitly told me above that the "end of the service on these different days" was not part of the question you asked and made fun of me for encouraging you to edit your question. Next time, just use the tools we provide you (especially editing) to improve your question before wasting people's time getting answers you don't really want.