# Location of kaddish titkabel during shacharit

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, kaddish, musaf

Why is the *kaddish titkabel* after *shacharit* on a regular weekday (or indeed any day without *musaf* e.g. Chanukah), deferred until after (*keriat hatorah*) *ashrei* and *uva letzion*?

One may have expected it to always come after *chazarat hashatz* (or *tachanun* or *hallel* where relevant) as that would seem to be the conclusion of the core *shacharit* service. This is indeed what we do on Shabbat, Yom Tov, Chol HaMoed and Rosh Chodesh, where it is consistently recited before *keriat hatorah*.

Does its recitation after *uva letzion* on a weekday imply that (*keriat hatorah*) *ashrei* and *uva letzion* are viewed as part of the *shacharit* service?

Conversely, does its location on *musaf* days imply that *keriat hatorah* and *ashrei* (and *uva letzion*) are not part of *shacharit* on those days (and maybe even become part of the *musaf* service)?

(Partly inspired by discussion on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78505/why-tiskabel-after-hallel-on-rosh-hodesh-and-not-other-weekdays-of-hanukka).)

Comment: The location before Torah reading is the more intuitive one since the Amida is now over. You could read the Torah anytime during the day if you needed to. The other side of this question seems stronger: why when there is no Musaf do we push off Titkabbel till after things that are only tangentially related to Shacharit?

Comment: @DoubleAA Right. I have a vague recollection (but cannot track down a source) that we want to apply תתקבל צלותהון ובעותהון to the various requests we make during ובא לציון.

Comment: There are a number of answers given in rishonim, but that is the way they ask the question. (Italian Rishonim say we push it off so people don't leave Shul early; Rambam says we use it to signal the actual end of the service. I don't think you can conclude that the Torah reading is "part" of anything just based on the Kaddish location.)

Comment: Why do some shuls (ashkenazim) say ashei after putting back the sefer torah whereas sefardim before?

Comment: I think beureihatefilah.com explains this. But, it will probably take compiling info from several articles on their web site to compose an answer. I'll try what I can, but it may take a while. There is something specific about how Kaddish Titkabel is unique to the end of a "portion" of tefilla. But, you do ask an interesting curiosity as to what is happening on Shabbat / Yom Tov that is different from Mon. / Thurs. I don't think it's tiedto Torah reading, though; It's something else.

Comment: @patient Please ask that as a separate question

Comment: @DanF But I know the answer. It is that really everything has to be done when the sefer torah is out. Like blowing shofar and reading the megillah. But one also must not take off ones tefillin while the sefer tora is out. So ashkenazim being in a hurry say it afterwards. Sefardim do it correctly since they are are not in a hurry.