# Question about placement of 2nd Shacharit Ashrei in Nusah Ashkenaz

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, yom-tov, torah-service, chol-weekday

This is what I have seen listed in most Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim / occur in most Nusach Ashkenaz shuls:

When the Torah is read during Shacharit:

- On weekdays - The 2nd Ashrei is said after the Torah is returned to the aron
- On Shabbat and Yom Tov, Ashrei is said before the Torah is returned to the aron.

Why is there a difference between these two days?

Comment: I've wondered this for so long!  The more precise parallel is Shabbos+Yom Tov vs. Rosh Chodesh+Chol Hamoed because in both cases that Ashrei belongs to Musaf.

Comment: @Heshy I'm not following. Doesn't Musaph begin with the Chatzi Kaddish just prior to the Amidah?

Comment: Nope.  It can't - kaddish needs pesukim before it.  Ashrei before Musaf is equivalent to Ashrei before Mincha, or Pesukei Dezimra before Shacharis.  At Musaf on Rosh Chodesh and Chol Hamoed it gets Uva Letziyon attached to it just like the Ashrei of Mincha on Shabbos and Yom Tov.

Comment: If you go to a shul that has a break between leining and Musaf, they skip Ashrei and put back the Sefer Torah, then have the break, then say (יה אלי when relevant,) Ashrei, Kaddish, Musaf

Comment: @Heshy Interesting. So even though on Rosh Hodesh & Hol Hamo'ed the order is the same as on a regular weekeday that has no Musaph, somehow, these bceom Musaph. Does this mean that the reason for saying full Kaddish after Hallel is so that we are declaring that Shacharit has ended and this is now Muspah? That would mean that Torah reading is part of Musaph, too. And, the same would be true for Shabbat & Yom Tov. Re 2nd comment, not all shuls do the order this way. From what I have seen, very few Nusach Ashkenaz do what you mention.

Comment: Well... I would say Torah reading is not exactly part of either, it's kind of in between (remember one chazan takes it out and one puts it back).  And as I mentioned some shuls have a break after it.  But there is [one case](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.3), which unfortunately doesn't happen now, where there's separate leining for Shacharis and Musaf.  Although the davening was completely different then as there was a real korban Musaf so it's hard to extrapolate.

Comment: yes very few shuls do it that way.  Only ones that have a break between leining and Musaf.  Most often you see no break or occasionally a kiddush before leining.

Comment: Also do you know this person? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78508/11532 :)

Comment: If it matters, mizrachim put it back after _Ashrei_ on weekdays